# ecdf() function in Matlab not giving all the values in output

Tags: matlab, statistics, cdf, ecdf

I computed CDF of my empirical distribution using `ecdf()` function in Matlab for a distribution with `10,000` values. However, the output that I get from it contains only `9967` values. How can I get total `10,000` values for my CDF? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a distribution with 10'000 values you'd expect an output of length 10'001. Most likely, your distribution contains 44 NaNs, or duplicate values. The former you check with `sum(isnan(data(:))`, the latter with `length(unique(data(:))`.

```
>> out = ecdf(1:5)
out =
         0
    0.2000
    0.4000
    0.6000
    0.8000
    1.0000
>> length(out)
ans =
     6
>> out = ecdf([1:5,NaN,NaN])
out =
         0
    0.2000
    0.4000
    0.6000
    0.8000
    1.0000
>> length(out)
ans =
     6
>> out = ecdf([1:5,5,5])
out =
         0
    0.1429
    0.2857
    0.4286
    0.5714
    1.0000
>> length(out)
ans =
     6
```